# How can I make my tree view elements overflow past the parent div's width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am using [bootstrap-treeview](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview) to try to make a nice treeview within my MVC project. This control is available on NuGet so its easy to get started with it. The left hand div shows the tree and the right hand div shows the content of each element when clicked:

```
<body>
    <div id="tree" style="position:absolute; width: 20%; height: 100%; overflow: scroll"></div>
    <div id="content" class="list-group-item node-tree" style="position: absolute; left: 20%; width: 80%; height: 100%">This is where content goes once you click on a file or folder element.</div>
</body>
```

There is a slight problem, though. The content of the div with the ID = `tree` gets cut off:

[image]

Ideally, I would like these list elements to overflow to the right, beyond the size of the div with the ID = `tree`, as you can tell, because I have set `overflow: scroll`, so I do not want any text to wrap to a new line.

On runtime, it appends list elements as follows...

[image]

These list elements seem to have the following CSS:

```
.list-group-item {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

I have tried adding `white-space: nowrap;` to this CSS, which makes the text do what I want (and overflow with a scrollbar), but the background and border of each list element stay at the width of the parent (which is not what I want; I want them to also overflow all scrollable width just like I did with the text)!

[image]

What can I do to make each element of this list properly overflow past the bounds of the parent div they all exist under?

**Edit**: I've tried putting `overflow:visible` on all parent levels as well, but it did not work. It removed the vertical scroll bar and kept all list item background borders still restricted to the width of the `tree` div. I also found that setting `width = 10000px` on the `.list-group-item` CSS partially gives me what I want as well, but obviously this makes the backgrounds too wide and the scroll bar becomes too elongated. I want the width of all list elements to be equal to the width of the widest overflowing content.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to change the `display` to `table-row-group` and I had to add `white-space: nowrap`:

```
.list-group-item {
    position: relative;
    display: table-row-group;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:visible` to the parent element(s). You may need this at multiple levels, as each parent element could potentially restrict the content.

Comment: Hey Chris, I appreciate it. I tried putting `overflow:visible` on all parent levels, but it did not work. It removed the scroll bar and kept all list item background borders still restricted to the width of the `tree` div.